# What is this HOME command?

Tags: zsh, shell-builtin

I'm able to run a command named "HOME" which appears to be equivalent to `cd && echo "~"`.
But I can't figure out where it's defined:

```
$ pwd
/tmp
$ which HOME
HOME not found
$ type HOME
HOME not found
$ man HOME
No manual entry for HOME
$ HOME
~
$ pwd
/Users/tba
```

Is this a shell builtin?
It seems more like a failed attempt to print the fully-qualified path of my home directory.

I'm running ZSH (with Oh-My-Zsh) on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Probably part of the ratmangle that is Oh-My-Zsh...

Comment: @jasonwryan Likely -- I have OMZ installed

Comment: @cuonglm Gives "HOME not found"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`oh-my-zsh` enable two things, which cause this behavior:

- [AUTO_CD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTOCD): If command can not execute, and command is a directory name, perform `cd` to that directory
- [CDABLE_VARS](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CDABLEVARS): If the argument to a `cd` command (or an implied cd with the `AUTO_CD` option set) is not a directory, and does not begin with a slash, try to expand the expression as if it were preceded by a `~`

In your case, when typing `HOME`, `AUTO_CD` made `zsh` performed `cd HOME`, `CDABLE_VARS` made `zsh` performed `cd ~HOME`, `~HOME` was expanded to your home directory.

You can call `zsh` with `--xtrace` option to see what happened:

```
$ zsh --xtrace
$ HOME
...
+zsh:1> cd /home/cuonglm
~
....
```

Comment: You probably mean `$HOME` not `~HOME`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: It's `~HOME`, please read [this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) for more details.

Comment: Thanks -- I found the HOME named directory by typing "hash -d"